# CoreData: Converting a String into an NSManagedObject instance

Tags: swift, string, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsentitydescription

I've been working with CoreData for one of my iOS apps and wanted to build a helper function to turn a `String` representation of a CoreData entity into an `NSManagedObject` instance of that entity. I've just finished my first Swift course for my major and from my understanding, I assume the logic/implementation is fairly simple. I believe my implementation is wrong because Swift is my newest programming language. I'm trying to avoid hard-coding a solution because my intuition tells me there's a better, more general way to achieve my goal.

Example (Naïve Pseudocode):

```
func getEntity(from string: String) -> NSManagedObject {
    return string as! NSManagedObject
}
```

Desired Execution:

```
let stringRep = "Entity"
entity(from: stringRep)
```

`Entity`

Context:

Two of the CoreData entities I'm working with are `Category` and `Service`.

```
public class Category: NSManagedObject { }
public class Service: NSManagedObject { }
```

`Category` contains a relationship to many `Service` entities and my other helper functions in `AppService` access CoreData using that relationship.

`CategoryTableViewController` has three static cells, each containing a `String` representation of the entities for `Category`.

I'm passing the selected `String` representation of an entity such as `Service` during `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` to the next `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`.

Using the new helper function, I will be able to ambiguously fetch from CoreData with the `String` representation and display the data in the `UITableView`.

My ultimate goal is to cut out unnecessary functions in `AppService` with the function below.

```
func get(_ entities: String, for category: Category) -> NSFetchedResultsController<T> {
    let someEntity = getEntity(from: entities)
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<someEntity> = someEntity.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", category)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    return createFetchedResultsController(for: fetchRequest)
}
```

Example:

```
get("Service", for: category)
```

Comment: You can't do that because `String` and `NSManagedObject` are not related. And `NSManagedObject` is not an entity.

Comment: I clarified it. That's just how I write pseudocode for Swift because of the language's semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object of a certain entity based on the entity name. As always, you will need your managed object context.

First you have to get the `NSEntityDescription`:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Widget", in: context)
```

Then you can create the object:

```
let newWidget = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, in: context)
```

However, it would be much better to use the subclass. It includes the entity information automatically.

```
let newWidget = Widget(context: context)  // much easier
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! Documentation was a bit vague on `NSEntityDescription` and how to use it. It should fit perfectly into my `AppService`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in that way...

1,Suppose there is an Entity names as "Person", in that you have an attribute as "name"

2, have an NSManagedObject something like xx12145ac through fetch query 
OR
Create a new NSManagedobject of person

3,once you have that object of type Person then you can set

myPersonObj.name = "SomeOne" as! String

I hope that will help you out!!!

Do let me know if you face any issue .. :)